# myBatis unable to openSession, selenium integration and myBatis

Tags: java, testing, selenium, integration, mybatis

Here is sample code for the @beforeTest method:

```
String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new ( SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();  
here couldnot open the  connection    

and the output testing under testNG is:
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setupPermission
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:  
Error opening session.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException  
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException  
------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use Connection, but not sure what kind of Connection myBatis is using in the code below:

```
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(Connection con);
```

Answer (score 0):

`openSession` method requires instance of `java.sql.Connection`. You may find [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) helpful.